# Using QuantLib for bonds with irregular coupon payments

Tags: programming, bond, quantlib

Could you please help properly use QuantLib python library to estimate different metrics of bond with uncommon coupon payment periods? For example, I have a bond, which pays coupon each 182 day (26 weeks). Following code sets up the schedule and the bond:

```
issueDate = ql.Date(19,6,2019) #05.06.2019
maturityDate = ql.Date(16,3,2039) #16.03.2039
tenor = ql.Period('26W') 
calendar = ql.Russia()
bussinessConvention = ql.Following
#bussinessConvention = ql.Unadjusted
dateGeneration = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
monthEnd = False

schedule = ql.Schedule (issueDate, maturityDate, tenor, calendar, bussinessConvention, bussinessConvention, dateGeneration, monthEnd)
dayCount = ql.Actual365Fixed()

compounding = ql.Compounded
cleanPrice = 105.45
ytm  = 0.0728
couponRate = 0.077
coupons = [couponRate]
settlementDays = 1
faceValue = 100

fixedRateBond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlementDays, faceValue, schedule, coupons, dayCount)
```

The seems correct, but when I try to calculate YTM I got wrong result (should be 7.28%) probably due to ql.Semiannual freqency:

```
fixedRateBond.bondYield(cleanPrice, dayCount, ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual) 

7.170206456184388
```

Is there any away to correctly estimate YTM, dirtyPrice, duration and other things for such bond?

Comment: Not sure about Russian OFZs, but for Mexican MBONOS/UDIBONOs (also every 26 weeks), if the coupon falls on a holiday, it is always bumped backwards, and both coupons are adjusted for the number of days. Do your projected cash flows always match "official" cash flows?

Comment: @Dimitri, yes the calculated cash flow matches the official one both in dates and volumes (up to rounding effect). I think the problem is with `fixedRateBond.bondYield(cleanPrice, dayCount, ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual)`, which requires frequency. It should be something like ql.Period('26W') instead of ql.Semiannual, but it does not work that way.

Comment: QuantLib may not be as good at supporting various emerging markets bonds quirks, including 182 days https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues/731 as some internal libraries I worked with. Some Russian bond rounding rules don't seem to be in QL either.  https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues/896

Comment: `fixedRateBond.bondYield(cleanPrice, dayCount, ql.Compounded, ql.Annual,ql.Date(5,6,2019))` gets you 7.28%

Comment: IMHO, yield is to be annualized, hence `ql.Annual`. Also, the evaluation date needs to be set somewhere; either thru `ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date(5,ql.June,2019)` or directly in the `bondYield` function. NB: I only **guessed** from your commented code section that you want to calculate YTM as of 2019-06-05...

Comment: @Kermittfrog Sorry, if the initial post was not very clear, the date should be `ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date(9,7,2021)` as I took real numbers from the exchange. Setting `ql.Annual` indeed produces 7.28%, but I struggle to understand the logic behind it. If the bond pays coupons twice a year, why should we use annual frequency?

Comment: The **coupon** is roughly semiannual, i.e. the cashflows take place about every 26W and the cash flow size is determined by `Nominal * coupon * YearFraction`. The discount rate (the yield) is commonly defined as an annually compounded rate, i.e. the discount factor $D(r,\tau)=\left(1+r\right)^{-\tau}$ is defined for $\tau$ year fractions. If you have a semiannual rate then, roughly, $D(r,\tau)=\left(1+0.5*r\right)^{-2*\tau}$. So for example, a 20% rate with semiannual compounding equals a 21% rate with annual compounding. HTH?